IOzone Filesystem Benchmark WEIRD Results on EXT4
I'm currently using an i7 with 32 GB of RAM to measure ext4 performance. However, I've encountered some unusual results when testing with 8 GB and 16 GB files.
Shouldn't the performance increase instead of decrease? The buffer cache should be taking action and improving the results, not making them worse. In the 16 GB scenario, the file size was 18 GB, and I have no desktop environment; it's solely a testing build.

[![Read Report][2]][2]
[3[![]][2]][2]: 

Performance ? You mean GB/s ? Decrease ? Do you mean the sudden decrease starting from 16GB filesize ? Well it does not appear "unusual" to me compared with other benchmarks (for example https://concurrent-rt.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/RedHawk-Throughput-Performance.pdf)

But I have 32GB ram, it should decrease on 32GB file not on 16GB.

You get 32GB ram ? Well… you'll have notice that the system used for the bench I linked to… as well. You'll have also noticed that write operations performances drop from even more earlier (4GB). So no ! Sorry, your results are neither weird nor unusual.
